# smartparens with LaTeX to deal with \begin \end environment and markup commands

Tags: latex, auctex, smartparens

How can I configure `smartparens` to treat `\begin ...\end` environments, and commands, e.g., `\textbf`, delimiters so that I can navigate them, e.g., using `sp-forward-sexp`.